# TEXTBOX REQUIRED POPUP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to I make a sweet alert error popup when form required textbox is empty and user clicked submit button. I want show instant popup danger alert that **%This TextBox Is Required%** in sweet alert. Such like JavaScript alert when textbox empty different is , that is js alert and I am talking about sweet alert instead of simple js alert. Please please help...

Answer (score 1):

here is sweet alert if input text is empty

```js
$('input[name="submit"]').on('click', function() {
  if ($('input[name="fullname"]').val() == "") {
    swal("fullname is required", '', 'error');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="fullname">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: What would the html?

Comment: @John_Cartor, what do you mean, i don't understand

Comment: Ok. i will create in fiddle, so you check it out there

Comment: You were might right actually I write script before html that's why problem was came. Could you tell me what about when we user multi textbox and if it empty alert say that specific textbox is empty.

Comment: @John_Cartor, i updated with error message, please check it out

Comment: Show textbox name in alert to indicate specific input box .How?

Comment: I has been updated tour fiddle too.. now it shows error..

Comment: @John_Cartor, error in fiddle, remaining you have to search and try on your own

Comment: Ok I has been resolve it but dear minimum you must help multi textbox issue . When I add other textbox it not working. Please help in multi textbox box ..

Comment: ok, @John_Cartor, i will help, what your expecting?

Comment: I want add two more textbox with different name like email and phone number textbox. Where If email pattern and phone patter would wrong or empty show alert .

Answer (score 0):

you need to check here you use jquery `trim` and `val` function.

**val**:  Get the current value of input

**trim**: Remove the whitespace from the beginning and end of a string.

```js
$('#button').on('click', function(){
 if($.trim($('input[type="text"]').val()) == ''){
     swal("Input can not be left blank")
     return false;
   }
   return true;
})
```

```css
.swal-footer { 
  text-align:center !important;
}

.swal-button {
  background-color: red;
 
} 

.swal-button:focus {
 outline: none;
 box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>


<form action="#" method="POST">
     <input type="text" name="fullname">
          <input type="text" name="lastname">
     <input type="submit" value="submit" id="button" name="submit"> </form>
```

Comment: Thank you it is working but How I move alert "OK" button in center without any btn border?

Comment: add `.swal-footer { text-align:center !important; }` to css your css

Comment: if this answer help you. please accept this answer. :)

Comment: Thank you! I accept. But what about multi textbox. When I added one more textbox it not work for other why?

Comment: For example please

Comment: check updated answer @John_Cartor

Comment: Is it possible to change btn color , hover color and hide border of btn defaultly ? Increase btn size too...

Comment: You haven't updated yet..

Comment: you can update button size and color in `.swal-button` class

Comment: Sir thanks, but looks might you ignore my question , how I add other text box of e-mail and phone when it empty or invalid pattern show swal alerts.please this last question pls help via provides script

Comment: please first try by your self.

Comment: Is any other way to hide this code such like php?

Comment: I doing this but not working...`if ($('input[name="firstname"]') ||  $('input[name="lastname"]').val() == "") {`